# OuterArray.indexOf(innerArray) не находит вложенный массив

Tags: массивы, javascript

Делаю упражнение 3 из главы 5 книги Eloquent javascript.
Видимо, что-то путаю в синтаксисе, получаю неожиданный результат.

```
var centuries = [];
for (person in ancestry) {
    var century = (Math.ceil(ancestry[person]["died"] / 100));
    if (centuries.indexOf(century) ===-1) centuries[century] = [];

    centuries[century].push(ancestry[person]["died"] - ancestry[person]["born"]);

    console.log("age", ancestry[person]["died"] - ancestry[person]["born"]);
    console.log("cent", century);
}
```

Хочу в результате получить массив массивов с веками и продолжительностями жизни в них:

```
[18:[75,30,28],19:[67,35,88],20:[45,94,65]]
```

Почему-то на следующем проходе условие не срабатывает, и внутренний массив затирается пустым, дело видимо в некорректном использовании `indexOf` в условии? И в итоге получаю массив вида:

```
[18:[28],19:[88],20:[65]]
```

Что я делаю не так?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/konst54/tnLf20gy/1/) с исходными данными и полным кодом.

Comment: используете indexOf на объекте вместо in

http://jsfiddle.net/tnLf20gy/2/

Comment: @Etki , тоже полезное решение, спасибо! Есть ли какие-то значимые отличия от предложенного ниже (centuries[century] === undefined) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция indexOf ведет поиск по значениям в массиве, а не по самому индексу в нем, как вы пытаетесь делать. Поэтому у Вас каждый раз условие `centuries.indexOf(century) === -1` является верным и массив создается заново, теряя предыдущее значение.

Простой пример на ошибку:

```
var arr = [];
arr[20] = [];
arr.indexOf(20) === -1 //вернет true
```

Решается просто: `if (centuries[century] === undefined) centuries[century] = [];`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhmgt9rp/1/)

Comment: Ага, тоже нашел появление ошибки. Спасибо за пояснение природы ошибки и решение. Отредактировал вопрос.